# Java Backend for Android

Tags: java-ee, java, rest, spring

Пишу backend для мобильной платформы. Раньше писал только под Web-клиентов, есть уже почти готовое приложение написанное на Spring+Hibernate, необходимо переделать под REST JSON. Вот интересует как поступить с регистрацией, написанной на Spring Security и есть ли какие то нюансы с работой под mobile. Не нашел нормальных примеров. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас все-равно остается HTTP протокол. Все работает точно так же, за тем исключением, что вам понадобится работать с JSON. В Spring все для этого есть.

Comment: Да, но в Spring Security есть с чем повозиться(

Comment: @maxus раз повозитесь, разберетесь, потом будет легче

Comment: Спасибо, будем пробовать, примеров бы :)

Answer (score 1):

Spring действительно предоставляет почти всё что нужно для разработки REST приложений, но вот в части Spring Security & AJAX не всё так просто как хотелось бы -- наверняка понадобится переопределить пару-тройку классов попутно разобравшись как внутри устроен Spring Security.

По-поводу разработки под мобильные приложения, возможно, может быть полезен проект [Spring Mobile](http://www.springsource.org/spring-mobile):

- [Quick Spring Mobile 1.0 Tutorial](http://blog.teamextension.com/quick-spring-mobile-1-tutorial-944)
- [Creating a mobile version of your website with Spring Mobile and Sitemesh](http://blog.trifork.nl/2012/05/03/creating-a-mobile-version-of-your-website-with-spring-mobile-and-sitemesh/)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Mobile говорят хорош для моб сайтов, но не для обычных апп.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth вас спасет.

Если сайтец написан на спринге, заюзайте jackson  и почти сразу у Вас будут json  сервисы) [Пример](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

Comment: Спасибо, это я и так прекрасно знаю. Вот только не совсем понятно как OAuth заюзать именно под mobile.

Comment: борюсь с этой же проблемой сейчас http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510980/java-spring-rest-%D0%B8-android?noredirect=1#comment619754_510980 вы смогли решитб проблему?