# Java spring Rest и Android

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-security

У меня есть rest service back-end которого написан на java.
Используется Spring Security. Какие шаги мне нужно сделать для того, чтобы сделать доступной авторизацию для андройд приложения? На данный момент всё работает в веб версии. Вот конфиг Spring Security.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        // отключена защита csrf на время тестов
        http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService);
    }
```

P.S. Или никаких шагов делать не надо и не важно кто выступает в роли клиента. (Через постмен авторизацию сделать получается) Мне интересен сам подход, нужно ли отдельно что-то реализовывать для того, чтобы авторизация через андройд приложение была возможна?

Comment: авторизация не нужен. используйте просто token - ы и все

Comment: а почему моя авторизация не годится?